# Visual Studio 2019 - open files with specific encoding (e.g. 437)

Tags: c++, c, character-encoding, visual-studio-2019, codepages

I got some legacy projects, with a source code encoding of `IBM437/CP437`. They **need** to be encoded that way at the moment, so please refrain from recommending a switch to utf-8.

So far I have unfortunately not found exactly what I need.
I experimented a lot and searched for several hours, yet my best workaround is the following:
While having the project opened in solution explorer, right click -> open with -> [C++ Source Code Editor (with encoding)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PMg2.png).
In this huge dropdown I can choose the file encoding I need [OEM United States - Codepage 437](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQUBg.png).
This is exactly what I need, but preferably automatic / persistent.

In the "Open With" window, the "C++ Source Code Editor (with encoding)" can also be set as default. This is a step in the right direction already, yet not at the right destination! With this setting, every time I open one of the files, I still need to use the dropdown and select the correct codepage every single time!

If anyone have anidea how to get this to work automatically, this would be great!

Most of the search results are about saving files in specific codepages, rather than opening them.
I tried playing around with .EditorConfig, yet it seems to support only like 5 codepages.
Also looked into the VS extensions and tried some. The `FileEncoding` extension looked promising, but it seems to just use .EditorConfig below the surface, since it's limited to the same few codepages.

Side note: I would even be perfectly fine with my Visual Studio opening all files in this codepage (for editor). So if someone knows a hack in that direction, it would be good too.
For example if I change the whole system codepage via registry keys:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP=437 (this is usually default for Western Europe)
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP=437 (ANSII Code Page)
```

It might work too, yet it's super dirty and system wide. Therefore I would rather live with the manual selection every time...

Also I could live with a shortcut, switching to the desired codepage. I used this approad in notepad++ for quite some time and got used to it. There I had a shortcut, e.g. ALT+X, switching to OEM US.

**To summarize this up:**

My perfect solution would be similar to the `Open With -> C++ Source Code Editor (with encoding)` workaround, but without having to select the codepage every single time!